# What is this language construct?

Tags: c#

Going through some old VB code I'm converting to c# I came across this:

RejectedCharacter:

What the heck is that, and why haven't I seen it before?

Comment: This is not the proper place to ask this question. You need to move to the Programmers Stack Exchange http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is for more specific questions. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a `labeled statement`.  You may find a `goto` that points to this label.  This is deemed bad practice.

Comment: You haven't seen it because it is universally deemed bad practice and usage of `goto` statements spawns demons from other dimensions into this world.

Comment: See [here](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/7/7a/goto.png) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a label, used with GoTo statements.

See MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Holy... Good luck, buddy.